# MongoDB - mongohub gui - queries by _id objectid type

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am using MongoHub GUI for MongoDB: http://mongohub.todayclose.com/

I would like to be able to query by ObjectId as this is what MongoHub is returing for _id. How to do this, something like {"_id":"4d1b4687a6d5437619000000"} is not working??

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it has been fixed in recent MongoHub release. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
{"_id": ObjectId("4d1b4687a6d5437619000000")}
```

check [this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs) for more details

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if MongoHub is broken in the case of supplying a function in a query (`ObjectId`, as galimy rightly suggested). If you enter the query as galimy suggested, then copy and paste the full query that MongoHub *says* it's going to execute (grayed out above the Query text input) into a connected `mongo` CLI console, it works fine.

I would recommend learning to use the `mongo` console -- I've found two bugs in 5 minutes of playing with MongoHub, and when you're typing in JSON for your queries anyway the GUI is doing very little for you.

Answer (score 1):

`{"_id": { $oid: "4d1b4687a6d5437619000000"}}` definitely should work. Java MongoDB driver implicitly creates ObjectId object in the object has `'$oid'` property.
Also all the same is for date using '$date' property.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately it was a mistype: internal $id should be $oid.

Comment: I uninstalled it, but I'll give it a try again. thanks.